# Android NDK on Mac OSX - quick install w/o Developer Tools

Tags: android, macos, osx-snow-leopard, android-ndk

I was just suggested to port some signal processing code to use the Android NDK to speed up the process, but I'm wondering 1. where to install it to and 2. what tool-chain to use

I'd prefer **not downloading** the 3.5GB Mac Developer Tools if possible.  I don't have access to an install cd that has it.  Want to try and get this done asap.  Does anyone know a way to get NDK development running quickly on OSX(snow leopard)?

Comment: Just download the ndk for mac, and follow the docs/INSTALL.txt.
Everything will be fine.

Comment: @qrtt1 that didn't exactly work for me.

Answer (score 3):

A version of make is included with the Android NDK. Simply add `{NDK install dir}/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin` to your `PATH` and you'll be able to build with the NDK.

Answer (score 1):

Unzip the NDK package for Mac OS X anywhere, then add it to your path. That's all you need to build code with the NDK. The NDK includes its own GCC-based toolchain, so you don't even need to have Xcode installed.

Go to the samples in the NDK and type ndk-build in the console to build them.

Comment: I get an error when I do that: 
ERROR: Cannot find 'make' program. Please install Cygwin make package
or define the GNUMAKE variable to point to it.

Comment: It doesn't have a make. It expects to use the one in the developer package. If your development platform is a Mac, then you ought to use the tools Apple provides. It will make your life a lot easier, even if you prefer another IDE to Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

If you install [Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/xcode.html), that will install Make.

Comment: The Xcode that came with the Mac should be sufficient. No need to download.

Comment: Is Xcode on one of the install DVD's?  It wasn't pre-installed on my Mac.

Comment: Yes, it's in the Developer package on the install DVD.

Comment: I don't have the install DVD and there is no make on my computer.  I really want to do this without installing Xcode.