# How do you install the required development tools for the Android NDK on Mac OSX 10.8.x

Tags: android-ndk, osx-mountain-lion

On the android developer site (http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html#Reqs) there are required development tools.

I got GNU Make 3.81 installed after following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767481/where-can-i-find-make-program-for-mac-os-x-lion) to install the latest xcode (at the time of this question v 4.6) and then download the "Command line tools". To make sure it was installed and what version it was I executed this command in my terminal:

```
$ make --version
```

**Q: What is the best way you would recommend to install the latest version of GNU Awk or Nawk on my Mac OSX 10.8.2? Do you recommend Awk or Nawk?**

I checked that my Mac has "awk version 20070501" installed after executing this command:

```
$ awk --version
```

I also saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454653/android-ndk-on-mac-osx-quick-install-w-o-developer-tools) which seems like a nice solution for both my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to download `android-ndk-r8d-darwin-x86.tar.bz2` file. Uncompress it and you are done. It includes needed tools for OSX like make and awk inside it (under `prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin` folder). No need for Xcode.

Comment: thanks! wish google specified that it was included in the tar file. Also it looks like you have to add {NDK install dir}/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin to your PATH and you'll be able to build with the NDK, as Bellinghammer said in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454653/android-ndk-on-mac-osx-quick-install-w-o-developer-tools)

Answer (score 3):

For those interested in actually installing GNU awk, I did the steps below.

First I downloaded GNU Awk (gawk) from one of the mirrors listed here:
www.gnu.org/prep/ftp.html

At this time of posting, I got gawk-4.0.2.tar.gz.

Then I followed the instructions here: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Installation

In short you follow these steps:

```
$ cd Downloads
$ tar -xvpzf gawk-4.0.2.tar.gz
$ cd gawk-4.0.2
$ sh ./configure
$ make
$ make check
```

More details are available [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Unix-Installation) for those commands above.

Answer (score 0):

An other place to get gawk, directly in pkg format. Will install on /usr/local/bin etc.
http://rudix.org/packages/gawk.html